# Angular 6 not displaying webp image

Tags: angular, webp

[image]I am using angular 6 and i notice that .webp images are not displaying and no problem for jpg,png . How to display webp image in angular 6 ?

It is working in google chrome and not working in mozilla firefox

Comment: Please add your code or a sample into https://stackblitz.com/ . we need to see you'r code.

Comment: This has not so much to do with angular but with browser support for WebP. According to https://caniuse.com/#search=webp firefox does not support it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<picture>
    <source srcset="test1.webp" type="image/webp">
    <source srcset="test1.jpg" type="image/jpg">
    <img src="test1.jpg" alt="test">
</picture>
```

Use picture tag to specify a set of fallbacks for less capable browsers. Browsers that don’t support  will just display whatever source is specified in the img tag.

Answer (score 0):

The **img** tag with the **source** attribute worked for me. Everything else can be read in the link below.

```
<img src="img/myAwesomeWebPImage.webp" alt="WebP rules.">
```

Source: https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).